# Is it possible to set the expiration of artifact to 'next-successful-build' in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, cicd, artifact

In the documentation, it seems that we can set the `expire-in` to several days or weeks. But I cannot decide an accurate fixed date. Is it possible to always keep the 'lastest' artifact, and remove the old one when a new one is successfully built?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okey. I found a solution here :

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#keep-artifacts-from-most-recent-successful-jobs

With this help, it can be easily reached.
The question should be closed.

---

Here's the instruction given by gitlab official.

> Keeping the latest artifacts can use a large amount of storage space in projects with a lot of jobs or large artifacts. If the latest artifacts are not needed in a project, you can disable this behavior to save space:
>
> - On the top bar, select Menu > Projects and find your project.
> - On the left sidebar, select Settings > CI/CD.
> - Expand Artifacts.
> - Clear the Keep artifacts from most recent successful jobs checkbox.
>
> You can disable this behavior for all projects on a self-managed instance in the instance’s CI/CD settings.

Comment: Then mark your reply as the correct answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).